# Spark Streaming Computation Jobs Division into Different Nodes

Tags: cluster-computing, distributed-computing, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Suppose we have 20 nodes in our cluster. Operation1 is to count the words in a time window of 1s, and operation2 is to sum up the results derived from operation1 over a time window of 60s (the result is of course the word count over a time window of 60s). But is there any way we can specify node 1-10 to perform operation1 and node 11-20 to perform operation2? Thanks!